Confusion on coordinate transformation matrix derivatives and Christoffel symbol transformation
Consider the coordinate transformation from $x^{\mu} \to x^{\bar{\mu}}$ given by the transformation matrix $\Lambda^{\bar{\mu}}_{\mu}$, and $\Lambda_{\bar{\mu}}^{\mu}$ for the inverse transformation.
From what I can understand, these transformation matrices are the Jacobians of the coordinate transformation and can be written as $\Lambda^{\bar{\mu}}_{\mu} = \frac{\partial x^{\bar{\mu}}}{\partial x^{\mu}}$ and $\Lambda_{\bar{\mu}}^{\mu} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\bar{\mu}}}.$
Edit: To save space, I will be using the following notation:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} = \partial_{\mu}$.
Now, under a change in coordinate, the Christoffel symbols are known to transform as:
$$\Gamma^{\bar{\alpha}}_{\bar{\beta}\bar{\mu}} = \Lambda^{\bar{\alpha}}_{\alpha} \Lambda_{\bar{\mu}}^{\mu} \left[ \Lambda_{\bar{\beta}}^{\beta} \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\beta\mu} 
 + \partial_{\mu} \Lambda_{\bar{\beta}}^{\alpha} \right].$$ Now, my question and confusion concerns the second term in the brackets.
Since, $\partial_{\mu} \Lambda_{\bar{\beta}}^{\alpha} = \frac{\partial^{2} x^{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\mu} \partial x^{\bar{\beta}}} = \frac{\partial^{2} x^{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\bar{\beta}} \partial x^{\mu}} = \partial_{\bar{\beta}} \Lambda_{\mu}^{\alpha}$ and given coordinate independence, that is $\Lambda_{\mu}^{\alpha} = \delta_{\mu}^{\alpha}$ which does not depend on $x^{\bar{\beta}}$, how come $\partial_{\mu} \Lambda_{\bar{\beta}}^{\alpha} = \partial_{\bar{\beta}} \Lambda_{\mu}^{\alpha} \neq 0$?
Is there something I am not considering that maybe prevents the switch of the coordinates $\mu$ and $\bar{\beta}$ or what am I missing?
Also, is it true to write that $\Lambda_{\bar{\mu}}^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} \Lambda_{\bar{\beta}}^{\alpha} = \partial_{\bar{\mu}} \Lambda_{\bar{\beta}}^{\alpha}$ by the chain rule?

Related: Do partial derivatives of different coordinate systems commute?. On a separate note, I think that 1. The notation you are using is quite confusing. Is that based on a certain book? 2. The way you expressed the Christoffel symbol isn't standard, there seems to be an extra differentiation that's uncalled for (assuming it's even correct which I didn't check).

@Amit Thank you very much for the related link which indeed does answer my first question (and main confusion)! On the separate note, I am not sure which notation isn't standard but the use of \Lambda for the Jacobian can be found in the book "A first course in General Relativity" by Bernard Schutz and the notation for the partial derivatives (e.g. \partial_{\mu}) can be found e.g. in "Relativistic QM and Field theory" by Franz Gross).

One confusing part is in identifying $\Lambda^\mu{}{\nu'}$ as the coordinate transformation itself. This is true only for linear transformations. When we then move from the linear Lorentz transformation to the more general definition:  $\Lambda^\mu{}{\nu'} \equiv \dfrac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\nu'}}$, It must be stressed that $\Lambda^\mu{}_{\nu'}$ is no longer the coordinate transformation itself but rather the elements of the Jacobian matrix of the coordinate transformation. It approximates the transformation locally but depends on the coordinates.
